# Copy directory to external from corrup driver

Tags: linux, hard-drive, copy

i need help critical, rifht now a HDD in my server its corrupt, need to force fsck over the partition (ext2 ubuntu 8.10), but I need to extrack files before the command for secure reasons..

I get mounted the partition in a live CD, and mount a external USB driver, and need to copy the files in the /var/www of corrup drive to the external.

The question, is I need to copy ALL files and dirs (cp -R), BUT IGNORING POSSIBLE CRC ERRORS.

It is possible?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a large enough (good) drive, try with [ddrescue](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/ddrescue.html). It will try to copy your whole drive/partition, and try to separate end exclude bad sectors. After that, you can mount that partition on the other system ("mount /somewhere/partitiondump.dd" /mnt -o loop"). You can also make a copy of it, and try running fsck on it, to see if it helps, or messes up things even more.

Comment: In this moment its not possible this because i dont have a good HD, only a external USB drivers with more folders in it.. and it urgent extract the data in the corrupt driver.

Comment: This just dumps your whole partition into a file. If your internal is 100gigs, then it will create a 100gb file (if the filesystem on the external drive supports that size - ntfs, ext3,...).  Otherwise, you can just mount the drive read-only, and rsync the data to another dir, and wait for IO/error timeouts on bad blocks (takes a while usually on consumer hard drives)